# what is new URL() syntax in css?

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader

On css-loader [changelog](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2021-07-14), it says `since v6 css-loader is generating new URL(...) syntax`. I dont quiet understand what the new URL syntax is.

What is the new URL() syntax and how is it different from this [url()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with the CSS *language*.

As part of building your bundle with Webpack, `css-loader` creates JavaScript code which pulls in your CSS files when it finds some line like `import 'my.css'` in your JavaScript source.

What that note is describing is a change in the syntax of the generated JavaScript to create a [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL). It's quite possibly an irrelevant implementation detail from your perspective.